# Phonegap Developer App and Content Security Policy

Tags: cordova

I'm using Phonegap Developer app to test my phonegap application. Recentyle I started receiving a console warning about a lacking Content-Security-Policy meta info. Since the Phonegap default template doesn't include any CSP then I decided to use the Cordova one. I've included the whitelist plugin (cordova-plugin-whitelist) and the following line in  of index.html:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

The problem is that after this the Phonegap Developer app doesn't update anymore. It gets stuck in "Connecting to device" in the default app template.
Console.log doesn't work also.

Am I missing something? What is the correct CSP?

Many thanks for any idea! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was bit by the same issue. Make sure you allow `unsafe-inline` scripts and stylesheets:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="
    default-src *;
    style-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
    script-src * 'unsafe-inline'; 
" />
```

For reference, [here](http://content-security-policy.com/) is the Content-Security-Policy documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the console plugin.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

Comment: Thank you Adam. The plugin is installed.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue you mentioned. 
first you have to add this to your `config.xml`

```
  <allow-navigation href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
```

Second: you have to add the CSP into your index:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">
```

There are a few things going on here, so let’s break it down into its constituent directives.

`'unsafe-eval'` Allows JavaScript from any of the above sources to use dynamic JavaScript evaluation: for example using eval().

`gap:` Cordova specific, the gap scheme enables JS <-> native communications for iOS.

`https://ssl.gstatic.com` Cordova specific, required for Android so that TalkBack (accessibility) works properly.

and here is the full documentation for each value meaning: 
http://content-security-policy.com/

Cheers.